# Topology Issue on stylized character

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, sculpting

I'm currently working on a stylized character. The goal of the project currently was to apply/learn topology on exaggerated characters. I've run into a problem because It seems that I've used the wrong type of topology approach. I've been following Danny Mac's video (I'll put a link for it below), great tutorial, but It seems like I've interpreted vertex for vertex of what he was doing instead of understanding the whole concept and mechanics of retopology for characters.

Any suggestions on how I could go about fixing it?

Thanks

Link to Danny Mac's Retopology Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L8eZAwmG2E

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: yes it looks like if you didn't adapt the topology to the particular face of your character but only stretch a topology made for another face, for example we would expect the chin to be an extrusion, also, in front view, you lack topology around the mouth, and what happens around the ear need some corrections, etc... (I'm not a master in face topology, but that's what seems to me)

Comment: Thank you so much, I redid the retopology with tweaking and improvement, and it's looking a lot better